# Adding an input to a stripe form

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

I'm trying to customize the stripe checkout form but I have no idea of how to add an input. I would like to add "phone number" and "name" to create a charge AND a customer. 
Do you have any idea of how I can do this?

```
<form action="paiement.php" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-zip-code="true" 

    data-key="pk_test_uYSRAdQpdYgrGLiyrkNA3EjA"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Example charge"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="eur"
    >
  </script>
</form>
```

This is the code that I'm supposed to customize.

Comment: You can't with the checkout API, you'll need to implement a custom Stripe form and handle it that way - https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can I do it with stripe js and elements?

Comment: See my answer below, should help you get started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to implement those custom fields with the Stripe checkout method. According to the docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout - there are no optional or mandatory fields you can add.

You'll need to use https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js in order to implement a custom form, process the payments on a backend, and handle the customer / charges via Stripe API. This can be done by standard HTML with your choice of backend language to process the charges and customers.

To learn how to create charges: https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges

To learn how to create customers: https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in the customers part of the api, there is no input for the name, where do I add it?

Comment: That would be a standard HTML field in your form. You'd store that information somewhere on your server. Stripe doesn't actually need that information, not even for it's customer API. You could, however, send it as metadata https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer